# How to get the counter value that is initiated in a method

Tags: java, android, onconfigurationchanged

I'm building an app that dynamically generates Buttons.  Saving the buttons through onSaveInstanceState does not work since I can't save UI elements through that so the option that makes the most sense is to recreate the views per orientation change.  I know exactly how to do that (overriding the onConfigurationChanged method) but my problem is that I'm not able to get the current counter value.  The counter variable is global but its not initiated.  It increments inside the onFloatActionButtonClick to keep a check on how many buttons I've added but I can't access that inner value from onConfigurationChanged method to recreate the same amount of buttons that were destroyed through the orientation change.

All help is appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int counter = 0;

    FloatingActionButton addingSemester;
    Button semesterButton;
    LinearLayout semesterLayout;
    GridLayout semesterGridLayout;

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams portraitLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addingSemester = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addActionButton);
        semesterLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

        semesterGridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.semester_grid_layout);

        semesterButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.delete) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Delete entry")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete everything?")
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                                    semesterGridLayout.removeAllViews();
                                } else if (!MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                                    semesterLayout.removeAllViews();
                                }
                                counter = 0;
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
                return true;
            }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    public void onFloatActionButtonClick(View view) {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        double width = (size.x)/3;

        semesterButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);
        if (counter < 8) {
            semesterButton.setId(counter + 1);
            semesterButton.setText("Semester " + (counter + 1));
            semesterButton.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            semesterButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            portraitLayoutParams.setMargins(24, 24, 24, 24); // keep this line

            if (MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
                params.setMargins(24, 24, 24, 24);
                params.width = (int) width;
                params.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                semesterButton.setLayoutParams(params);
                semesterGridLayout.addView(semesterButton);
            } else if (!MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                semesterLayout.addView(semesterButton);
                semesterButton.setLayoutParams(portraitLayoutParams); // keep this line
            }

            counter++;
            setOnLongClickListenerForSemesterButton();

        } else if (counter == 8) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You cannot add more than 8 semesters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Screen is in Orientation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Screen is in Landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void setOnLongClickListenerForSemesterButton() {
        semesterButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                final Button b = (Button) v;
                b.setTag(b.getText().toString());
                b.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                b.setText("Delete");

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Delete entry");
                        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                                    semesterGridLayout.removeView(b);
                                    for (int i = 0; i < semesterGridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                        ((Button) semesterGridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setText("Semester " + (i + 1));
                                    }
                                } else if (!MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                                    semesterLayout.removeView(b);
                                    for (int i = 0; i < semesterLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                        ((Button) semesterLayout.getChildAt(i)).setText("Semester " + (i + 1));
                                    }
                                }
                                counter--;
                            }
                        });
                        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                b.cancelLongPress();
                                b.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimary));
                                b.setText(b.getTag().toString());
                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        });
                        builder.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is where I'm trying to hide my MenuItem when there are no views.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        Configuration newConfig = new Configuration();

        if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            if(semesterLayout.getChildCount() == 0){
                item.setVisible(false);
            }
        }

        if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            if (semesterGridLayout.getChildCount() == 0){
                item.setVisible(false);
            }
        }

        int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.delete) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Delete entry")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete everything?")
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                                    semesterGridLayout.removeAllViews();
                                } else if (!MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                                    semesterLayout.removeAllViews();
                                }
                                counter = 0;
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
                return true;
            }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `onConfigurationChanged()` is called then the activity will not be restarted by Android and you don't need to save the instance of the activity to restore it. But be careful, from the documentation

> Remember: When you declare your activity to handle a configuration change, you are responsible for resetting any elements for which you provide alternatives. If you declare your activity to handle the orientation change and have images that should change between landscape and portrait, you must re-assign each resource to each element during onConfigurationChanged().

The `counter` variable is global so you can access it from the `onConfigurationChanged()` method and the value of the variable will be preserved when the screen orientation changes, because Android will not restart the activity. You can access it as you do in your `onFloatActionButtonClick(...)` method

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    System.out.println(counter); //Print the counter value
}
```

Using `onConfigurationChanged()` will preserve the activity instance and views that have been added during runtime (views add when a button is pressed for example). If you want to achieve the same result by restarting the activity, you need to save the `counter` value, then in your `onCreate` method you have to restore the `counter` value and repopulate the layout based on that value.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the counter value
    savedInstanceState.putInt("counter", counter);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addingSemester = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addActionButton);
    semesterLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

    semesterGridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.semester_grid_layout);

    semesterButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore the counter value
        counter = savedInstanceState.getInt("counter");

        //Repopulate the layout
        for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            addSemesterButton(i);
        }
    }
}

public void addSemesterButton(int id) {
    //This is an edited version of onFloatActionButtonClick(...) method
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    double width = (size.x)/3;

    semesterButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);
    semesterButton.setId(id + 1);
    semesterButton.setText("Semester " + (id + 1));
    semesterButton.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    semesterButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    portraitLayoutParams.setMargins(24, 24, 24, 24); // keep this line

    if (MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
        GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(24, 24, 24, 24);
        params.width = (int) width;
        params.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        semesterButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        semesterGridLayout.addView(semesterButton);
    } else if (!MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
        semesterLayout.addView(semesterButton);
        semesterButton.setLayoutParams(portraitLayoutParams); // keep this line
    }
}
```

For more info https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

Comment: And how do I reference this saved value of counter from my onConfigurationChanged method?

Comment: So prior to your edit, I decided to ditch `onConfigurationChanged()` and handle my configuration change in the onCreate within the `if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore value of members from saved state
            counter = savedInstanceState.getInt("counter");`.  It works and gets the recent value of counter but does not automatically repopulate the layout when rotation happens.  I pasted my code in the edit.

Comment: You need to repopulate the layout when the activity is restarted. As you wrote, views cannot be saved into the bundle when you save the activity instance. But you can save the counter value. So when you restore the counter value in your onCreate(...) method you have to repopulate the layout with a simple cycle (just add n views to the layout where n equals the value of counter)

Comment: How to I do the automatic repopulating?  That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: look at the edited answer, I wrote a complete example of how to do that

Comment: Now I have repeated code between addSemesterButton and onFloatActionButtonClick.  How do I clean this up?

Comment: If you have repeated code, it's better to put that code into a method and call when you need it. Just create a method that add a button to the layout, like the one in my answer, than call it from onFloatActionButtonClick and onCreate when you add a button instead of copy-pasting the code all the time. Anyway, I've looked at you edited question and I think that this 'while (counter < childCount){' wouldn't work because childCount will always be 0 at that point, counter instead will be > 0

Comment: I got it working.  Thanks.  One more question if you don't mind.  I'm trying to hide my MenuItem when there are no views in the layout.  I tried doing something like my above edit but my `getChildCount()` is throwing an error each time I try to use it.